# Present UIAlertController in another UIAlertController cause Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

I want to present a `UIAlertController` with `UIAlertControllerStyleAlert` style while dismissing a `UIAlertController` with `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` style. In other words, I want to present an alertview after tapping an option from an actionsheet. But no alertview is presented, only this message in the log appears:

> Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is
>   deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior

Here my code:

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"MyApp" message:@"Info" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        // Cancel button tappped.
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        }];
    }]];

    [actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Credits" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"Credits"
                                      message:@"Here some text in the alertview..."
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                    actionWithTitle:@"Close"
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                    {
                                        //Handel your yes please button action here


                                    }];

        [alert addAction:yesButton];

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
            // try to present the alertview
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }];
    }]];

    // Present action sheet.
    [self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The actionsheet is working, the alertview not. The actionsheet is presented from a `UITableViewController`. Every help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed..here is the code. 
You do not need to dismiss in order to load the the AlertController.

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"MyApp" message:@"Info" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    // Cancel button tappped.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}]];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Credits" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

    UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Credits"
                                  message:@"Here some text in the alertview..."
                                  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                actionWithTitle:@"Close"
                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                {
                                    //Handel your yes please button action here


                                }];

    [alert addAction:yesButton];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}]];

// Present action sheet.
[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Just tried that on an empty project by adding that code in - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated and works fine.

Hope that helps

Comment: What a stupid mistake I made...thank you! Thanks also to @Mike Taverna

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are calling [self presentViewController] within the completion block of [self dismissViewControllerAnimated].

The alert view controller that you are trying to present is being deallocated because it is a local variable within the self view controller which has been dismissed.